# How to open comments from disqus in my iOS app

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, disqus

I have RSS reader, and it's using disqus.com to comment stories, but I can't open only comments from my webpage.

I've tried to remove text from HTML, but it is removing comments too.
I've tried to use api, but I can't make response from server visible.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not officially documented but you can find an RSS link in our embed which is unique for each thread. It sits next to the "Subscribe by email" link.

Thread RSS links are assembled fairly simply. Using pseudo-code, the assembly looks like:

`'http://' + disqus_shortname + 'disqus.com/' + thread_slug + '/latest.rss'`

Using our latest blog post as an example, the RSS link looks like:
http://disqus.disqus.com/new_feature_always_know_where_your_comment_went_62/latest.rss

A thread's slug can be pulled using our [threads/details API method](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios this is a great solution that handles Disqus integration into iOS apps. Supports pretty much all you need from Disqus in an app.

Answer (score 0):

there is a description on disqus forums:

> John Campbell 1 year ago
>
> It does, with an URL of http://[your disqus site id].disqus.com/latest.rss
>
> Such as http://jesus.disqus.com/latest.rss
>
> It can be tracked with feedburner or yahoo pipes, etc.

Comment: I need to open comments from current page. This RSS feed is for all site.